# Success message "Domain domain1 started." not logged but console is accessible when starting GlassFish

Tags: glassfish, asadmin

After installing Java EE6 SDK, I installed tutorial with update tool etc. As per Oracle documentation, I started glassfish using

> asadmin start-domain --verbose

There was no error in logs but there was no success message too and the command did not end execution, control did not return to dos prompt. Last line in logs was

> [#|2012-05-28T19:48:31.213+0530|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.jmx.org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver|_ThreadID=40;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JMX005: JMXStartupService had Started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://WIN-PZ021TGFDU4:8686/jndi/rmi://WIN-PZ021TGFDU4:8686/jmxrmi|#]

Any idea what may have gone wrong? Am able to access server and admin console on 8080 and 4848 resp.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior. The Glassfish verbose mode prints server log messages to `System.out` (in addition to the log file) and you can see it in the console window. If you don't get an error message everything is ok.

Ctrl-C will stop the server running in verbose mode and you get back to your command prompt.

If you want to see the success message, just start the server without the `verbose` option.